# Hibernate @ManyToOne optional=true fetches parent in a separate select with FetchType.LAZY

Tags: hibernate, annotations, lazy-loading, many-to-one

Hibernate optional `@ManyToOne` relationship still fetches the `Parent` in a separate select `optional=true` and `fetch=FetchType.Lazy`

**Child**

```
@ManyToOne //may not exist
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="parent_key1", insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="parent_key2", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    Parent parent
```

Note, that I can have a value for `parent_key1`, `parent_key2` columns existing in `Child` table but a corresponding `Parent` need not exist with this key, that's why the optional.

These are **not** final classes and any select on `Child` is fetching `Parent` again in a separate select with or without LEFT JOIN FETCH suggesting `optional=true` and lazy do not work.

Can `Parent` be lazy without compile time instrumentation using `@OneToOne`?

Comment: Your annotation doesn't define fetch=FetchType.LAZY, and doesn't define optional=true!? Your JoinColumns annotation is not properly ended. Please show us the real code. Moreover, optional doesn't mean what you think it means, and you should NOT have non-existing values in parent_col: it will lead to exceptions.

Comment: how else should I map a manyToOne relationship where the parent may not exist whereas the columns in child table can exist?

Comment: You might use the NotFound annotation. But this denotes a coherence problem in your data. It should never happen, and you should have a foreign key constraint in the database.

Comment: ended up populating another bean using constructor using select specific columns from table join...